# Import entire file in module

Tags: python, import, module

I have a folder structure like so:

```
main/
    __init__.py
    files/
         __init__.py
         a.csv
         b.yml
    subfolder/
          __init__.py
         code.py
```

In code.py, I want to use the files in the files folder as so:

```
# HOW DO I IMPORT a.csv and b.yml 
# from main.files import a -- this doesn't work
class Code():
     def func(file_a, file_b):
          # do something
```

Is this something I can do? How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If code.py is in the same folder as your files (.csv and .yml) you don't have to import them instead you can open them and read them within the function like so:

```
import csv
import yaml

file_a = 'a.csv'  
file_b = 'b.yaml'  

class Code():
 def func(file_a, file_b):
      with open(file_a) as f_obj:
          read = csv.reader(f_object)
          # do something with opened file
      
      with open("example.yaml", 'r') as stream: 
          another_read = yaml.safe_load(stream))
          # do something with opened file
```

I think your second file is supposed to be a .yaml file not a .yml file.